# How to use log4j in RCP application with Maven?

Tags: java, maven, log4j, swt, eclipse-rcp

I am working on a small RCP project which has Maven nature and now I wish to add log4j dependencies with that.
For that purpose what I did was :

1. Added log4j.properties under bin folder inside the project. bin is the folder where all the class files are getting generated. The file looks like this:

```properties
# Root logger option
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, stdout, file

# Redirect log messages to console
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.Target=System.out
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n

# Redirect log messages to a log file, support file rolling.
log4j.appender.file=org.apache.log4j.RollingFileAppender
log4j.appender.file.File=C:\\Srijani\\Personal Workspace\\RCP\\EditorApp\\log\\Application.log
log4j.appender.file.MaxFileSize=5MB
log4j.appender.file.MaxBackupIndex=10
log4j.appender.file.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.file.layout.ConversionPattern=%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} %-5p %c{1}:%L - %m%n
```

2. Added this dependency in pom.xml

```xml
<dependencies>
   <dependency>
    <groupId>log4j</groupId>
    <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.17</version>
   </dependency>
  </dependencies>
```

3. In java code I wrote like this:

```java
import org.apache.log4j.Logger;

import com.app.editor.constants.Constants;

public class DatabaseConnection {
    final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(DatabaseConnection.class);
}
```

This code does not creata any problem while compiling. But, while running the code, I got this error:

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench 4 0 2016-01-13 13:50:35.397
!MESSAGE Unable to create class 'org.eclipse.ui.internal.e4.compatibility.CompatibilityView' from bundle '55'
!STACK 0
org.eclipse.e4.core.di.InjectionException: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/log4j/Logger
    at org.eclipse.e4.core.internal.di.MethodRequestor.execute(MethodRequestor.java:62)
```

Note: I did not add anything to MANIFEST.MF and build.properties.
Please help!

Thanks

Update: Got the issue but not sure how to solve it. When I am downloading the jar manually and set it in the class path, I am able to use log4j in Eclipse RCP. But, when I am trying download it via Maven, it is not working. Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: You are getting NoClassDefFoundError, better you check once the Log4j-<Version>.jar file is downloaded or not under .m2(Repository). Also, you have to declare Log4j.properties file to tell system where to place the log file and all.

Comment: log4j.jar is already downloaded  at C:\Users\me\.m2\repository\log4j\log4j\1.2.17 folder

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "RCP project which has Maven nature"? How do you manage dependencies for RCP? How do you build and run your RCP project?

Answer (score 1):

If you use Maven in combination with Eclipse RCP you should consider using Tycho[1]. Tycho uses the MANIFEST-first approach, so that you don't need to edit the pom-files.

In addition you should put your log4j.properties into a fragment with the log4j-bundle as host-plugin.

[1] https://eclipse.org/tycho/

Answer (score 0):

I hope in this website explained clearly. It will helps to you.

http://www.mkyong.com/logging/log4j-hello-world-example/

My sincere suggestion is, before implement in project try to create one sample example. If it success, you can apply same into project.

Comment: I am following this website only. For sample project, I succeeded. But, when I am trying to apply it in an Eclipse RCP project, it is not working.

Comment: Do one thing, Clean and Build your project once.

Comment: Link-only answers are commonly frowned upon on SO because the link can become void. Could you add the essential parts from the source to your answer? (Did not downvote because I guess this is nevertheless helpful)

Comment: It seems like eclipse plugins related error, If I am not wrong. Also, externally copy the log4j jar and add it into web-inf/lib directory.